# Filename of workers in Symfony Gearman bundle

Tags: php, symfony, psr-0

On Symfony, I use Gearman to queue some jobs with [Ulabox GearmanBundle](https://github.com/ulabox/GearmanBundle/) as the application-side library.

I read how a worker should be created in the [readme](https://github.com/ulabox/GearmanBundle/blob/master/README.md) of the bundle, and understood that I should create a class in the `src/Acme/DemoBundle/Gearman/Worker`. What I didn't understood is: how should I name the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), which is the PHP autoloading convention, you class should be in a file with the same name than your class.

Example: `\Acme\DemoBundle\Gearman\Worker\FooWorker` will be contained in the file `Acme/DemoBundle/Gearman/Worker/FooWorker.php`

Take the time to read the linked spec, as it have more examples.

Comment: Ah, ok so maybe I'm wrong with it. Cause I thought i can have a namespace like

namespace Pr\GearmanBundle\Gearman\Worker;

The file is at src/Pr/GearmanBundle/Gearman/Worker/Worker.php

Am I wrong with this? Why do you call it FooWorker.php? I guess the name of the class should be "FooWorker" then; like the filename itsself?

Example: class FooWorker extends ContainerAwareWorker
{

Am I right with that?

Loads of thanks for your quick help and a kind weekend
Phil

Comment: The name is yours to choose, I named my class `FooWorker` as an example: your worker should be named something in relation with the job it do.

Comment: Hi Elwinar, ok that helped me really. I think I understood (in first steps) . I will try to go ahead :):) Thank you very much  ... kind regards